# Laravel API finding which longitude and latitude inside a radius

Tags: laravel, rest

My API response give my a list of apartments.
Each of my Apartments have a latitude and longitude.
I need to find which apartments are inside a radius given by the users(20km as example)
How i can implement a radius function in my API resource/controller?
I thought looping in my controller but i dont think it's a good idea.
(i need to filter in backend)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.